# Avoiding border effect in traffic modeling?

Tags: gis-principle, modelling, traffic

I'm creating a traffic model (using the Four-Step Travel Demand procedure).

I have a road network (grey lines and grey node) and traffic injector/attractor (orange lines and orange nodes) as it can be seen below:

[image]

So the traffic is injected/attracted in my network with those injectors/attractor.

The problem is that I obtain a strong border effect. Indeed I cannot take into account all the trips entering or leaving the network.

The following image show how the traffic flow is concentrated in the middle of my network:

[image]

How can I take into account the flow entering and leaving the network ?

Comment: just had a quck read on what you are working on, but for now I'm a noob in traffic modeling; still, I would somehow expect a pattern like yours in a (hierarchical) city network, i.e. higher concentration on primary roads/highways, no? could you explain (maybe only to me...) what you'd expect?

Comment: Indeed, the primary road will have a higher concentration than the residential road (for example), but if you look on the border of the map, even the primary road have almost no traffic flow. Why ? Because the model think that my analysis area is a closed world where no one enter or leave this area, but it is of course wrong. Perhaps that I should add some strong injector/attractor (representing the "outside" world) on the border of my analysis area, it's at the moment the only solution I can think of.

Comment: ah I see, thanks, yeah from what I read I expected many, if not all (some possibly temporary, e.g. parking garage etc.), injectors are also attractors of adjusted magnitude for traffic flow to make sense...